# Forecasting many stores sales with optimal reconciliation and regression

Tags: r, forecasting, multilevel-analysis, dynamic-regression

I am forecasting many stores sales via [the optimal reconciliation approach](https://www.otexts.org/fpp2/reconciliation.html). The problem is that forecasts are not as accurate as I would like.

**Edit:**

> Part of the problem is that a small subset of my stores have closed. I
>   would like to constrain their forecasts to be 0. How would I do that
>   with Robert Hyndman's package `hts`.

*Solved by removing closed stores.*

Also, we are aware of other factors, such as holidays and media, that have an impact on sales. Is there a way to do optimal reconciliation then [dynamic regression](https://www.otexts.org/fpp2/dynamic.html)? It would be nice to not only include a hierarchical forecast of past sales, but also one that includes marketing effects.

Comment: Why not remove the closed stores from the dataset?

Comment: If it is that simple then I don't mind doing that. I was not sure if there was extra care needed.

Comment: Also, It seems like each stores historical data can inform the forecast, even if the store has been closed for a few months. By deleting the store, I am deleting its historical contribution.

Comment: Not so much; the correlations between those stores' past sales and other stores' past sales are irrelevant going forward, because those stores are closed.  Also, if the subset of stores is small, removing them won't have much impact but will simplify the forecasting problem significantly.

Comment: I would look into [hierarchical forecasting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=hierarch*+forecasting+answers%3A1).